# A performance question in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I’m seeing a performance behavior in mysqld that I don’t understand.

I have a table t with a primary key id and three data columns col1, … col4.

The data are in 4 TSV files 'col1.tsv', … 'col4.tsv'. The procedure I use to ingest them is:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  col1 INT NOT NULL,
  col2 INT NOT NULL,
  col3 INT NOT NULL,
  col4 CHAR(12) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL );

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE      # POP 1
  'col1.tsv' INTO TABLE t (id, col1);  

ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

SET GLOBAL hot_keys.key_buffer_size= # something suitable 
CACHE INDEX t IN hot_keys; 
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE t;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpt;
CREATE TABLE tmpt ( id INT NOT NULL, val INT NOT NULL );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'col2.tsv' INTO TABLE tmpt tt;
INSERT INTO t (id, col2)    # POP 2 
  SELECT tt.id, tt.val FROM tmpt tt
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2=tt.val;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpt;
CREATE TABLE tmpt ( id INT NOT NULL, val INT NOT NULL );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'col3.tsv' INTO TABLE tmpt tt;
INSERT INTO t (id, col3)    # POP 3
  SELECT tt.id, tt.val FROM tmpt tt
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3=tt.val;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpt;
CREATE TABLE tmpt ( id INT NOT NULL, 
  val CHAR(12) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'col4.tsv' INTO TABLE tmpt tt;
INSERT INTO t (id, col4)    # POP 4
  SELECT tt.id, tt.val FROM tmpt tt
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col4=tt.val;
```

Now here’s the performance thing I don’t understand. Sometimes the POP 2
and 3 INSERT INTO … SELECT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queries run very fast with mysqld 
occupying 100% of a core and at other times mysqld bogs down at 1% CPU reading t.MYD, i.e. table t’s MyISAM data file, at random offsets.

I’ve had a very hard time isolating in which circumstances it is fast and
in which it is slow but I have found one repeatable case:

In the above sequence, POP 2 and 3 are very slow. But if I create t 
without col4 then POP 2 and POP 3 are very fast. Why?

And if, after that, I add col4 with an ALTER TABLE query then POP 4 runs
very fast too.

Again, when the INSERTs run slow, mysqld is bogged down in file IO 
reading from random offsets in table t’s MyISAM data file. I don’t even
understand why it is reading that file.

MySQL server version 5.0.87. OS X 10.6.4 on Core 2 Duo iMac.

---

**UPDATE**

I eventually found (what I think is) the answer to this question. The mysterious difference between some inserts being slow and some fast is dependent on the data.

The clue was: when the insert is slow, mysqld is seeking on average 0.5GB between reads on t.MYD. When it is fast, successive reads have tiny relative offsets.

The confusion arose because some of the 'col?.tsv' files happen to have their rows in roughly the same order w.r.t. the `id` column while others are randomly ordered relative to them.

I was able to drastically reduce overall processing time by using sort(1) on the tsv files before loading and inserting them.

Comment: what are you trying to do - straight answers only pls !!

Comment: It's reading that file because you are inserting into that file?

Comment: @f00: i am trying to ingest the TSV files into the table as described in the second and third sentences of the OP.

Comment: @Danosaure: It would appear so. For the first half hour or so of the POP 2 INSERT, all the disk IO is (random offset) reads from the data file of the table I'm inserting into. A few hours later it's a mix of reads and writes.

Comment: @fsb: Maybe unrelated... but I've seen my production server with dual CPU 64-bit run slower than a single CPU 32-bit less RAM on MySQL 5.0.x (with the same setup in my.cnf).  This does not happen with 5.1.x  Are you able to try this with another server to see if the same pattern occurs?

Comment: @fsb: Out of curiosity, why are you creating `NOT NULL` columns when you explicitly know that the columns will be `NULL` for the first "POP" and you are not even sure they will all be `NOT NULL` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty open question... here's a speculative, open answer. :)

> ... when the INSERTs run slow, mysqld is bogged down in file IO reading from random offsets in table t’s MyISAM data file. I don’t even understand why it is reading that file.

I can think of two possible explanations:

1. Even after it knows there is a primary key collision, it has to see what used to be in the field that will be updated -- if it is coincidentally the destination value already, 0 in this case, it won't perform the update -- i.e. zero rows affected.
2. Moreover, when you update a field, I believe MySQL re-writes the whole row back to disk (if not multiple rows due to paging), and not *just* that single field as one might assume.

> But if I create t without col4 then POP 2 and POP 3 are very fast. Why?

If it's a fixed-row size MyISAM table, which it looks like due to the datatypes in the table, then including the `CHAR` field, even if it's blank, will make the table 75% larger on disk (4 bytes per `INT` field = 16 bytes, whereas the `CHAR(12)` would add another 12 bytes). So, in theory, you'll need to read/write 75% more.

Does your dataset fit in memory? Have you considered using InnoDB or Memory tables?

**Addendum**

If the usable/active/hot dataset goes from fitting in memory to not fitting in memory, an orders of magnitude decrease in performance isn't unheard of. A couple reads:

http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2010/10/foursquare-outage-post-mortem.html

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/11/19/is-there-benefit-from-having-more-memory/

Comment: Interesting comments. Thanks. The row size is fixed. The data doesn't all fit in memory. It's a once, read often application. I don't think the  difference in row length between the two cases (with and without col4) can be the answer answer. That's a difference between 20 bytes per row and 32. The performance difference is something like 50 or 100 X. In the fast case, 20 million rows are inserted in 5 minutes, in the slow it's most of a work day.